# Is there an optimal position for user polls on a website?

Tags: design

I am in the process of designing a sports website. Users will visit to check the scores and fixtures of their team for various sports.

On the home page I am thinking of putting a user poll, just to engage with the community. At the moment I have a side bar on the right with some of the latest scores, for users' convenience. I have put the user poll as a widget below this section as it has less importance on my sports website.

Ideally, does a user poll have to be at the top of the page or does it mainly depend on the significance of the poll?

Is there any research that states that polls at the top of the page gets more votes than ones at the bottom or middle of the page?

Comment: It's great you're asking about research. The thing is, research about the effect of layout on conversion only applies to the specific context in which the research was done—so a specific combination of users, motivation, content, services, business drivers, and so on. If you're unconvinced, I recommend you subscribe to https://whichtestwon.com and after a few months you'll see how unpredictable the effect of design details are. Sorry if this answer isn't what you're looking for. :)

Comment: @JeromeR This is a good point - research is specific to contexts. So many questions on this site looking for research to show something that in all likelihood wouldn't apply to their situation.

Answer (score 1):

Your objective should be to not make the **Temporary Poll** on your website drive away the **Permanent Customer/User Base** you have.

By the above statement, I mean to say that your poll *should not interfere* with the actions of the user she/he is accustomed to.

Now, depending on what your poll is for, the positioning can be different.

**Articles** generally have a poll below the article to get an idea of what the Reader likes/ dislikes more.

For e.g.

### Which color iPhone are you going to pre-order?

1. Rose Gold (It's pink)
2. Space Gray
3. Gold
4. Silver

Now, the poll clearly depends on the article and the advantages and disadvantages of the color of the iPhone and the photos with it. So, it's not recommended to be put before the article.

Similarly for your website,the reason you're asking users to vote on a poll, is crucial.

If it's something that doesn't affect the customer/user base as much, try using [Strawpoll](http://strawpoll.me/). It works well with temporary polls.